# Does Flash 4 work in Windows 7?

Tags: flash

SWF generated in Flash 4 with embedded pics seem to display poorly (jagged) ONLY in Windows 7 IE - vector elements are fine.

see here: http://www.sycamoregraphics.co.uk/print.htm

any ideas for a quick fix?

Mark

Answer (score 2):

Resizing/re-scaling images (even if you scale them with aspect ratio) would still cause them to look pixilated.

- Resize the original images (by photoshop), don't resize/rescale from Flash itself
- Tweening/animating images may also cause them to look pixiliated
- Remember, how images are displayed and how clear they are can be different from browser to another.

Since your tweening the images, try changing the tween to keyframes, that might help

btw, why do you use Flash 4? Newer versions of Flash display images better

Comment: I must agree with evilReiko: Flash 5 was introduced in 2000 - ten years seem a bit long to keep backwards compatibility for.

Comment: Thanks for that - I had an old version on my PC - I've re-published the files through Version 9 (CS3) hopefully will do the trick - this is a gr8 site btw

Comment: Vote my answer up and click the green tick if you think its the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Set the `smoothing` property of the Bitmaps to `true`.